# Parse custom tags from RSS/XML using SimplePie

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplepie

I've just installed SimplePie to parse my RSS feeds to display on my site. I've tried their tutorial for grabbing custom XML tags, but things aren't working out.

The custom tag is: < odat:image>http://www.image.com/images/items/image.jpg< /odat:image>

I want to breakdown the tags into different variables so I can format the display of the information anyway I'd like. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Current SimplePie code:

```
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):?>

    <div class="item">
        <h2><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><small>Posted on <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?></small></p>
    </div>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try

```
$items = $feed->get_items();
foreach ($items as $item):?>

    <div class="item">
        <h2><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><small>Posted on <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?></small></p>
    </div>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

This should fix your problem

To get at the custom element within the feed you can use `get_item_tags()` an array of tags will be returned
http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_item_tags

if you inspect the array using print_r() you should be able to find the data you need and how to access it

Dc

Comment: How do I have it display the odat:image tag? Right now, it's only grabbing the title and description tag

Comment: see additional information, sorry I didn't include this, I saw what I thought was an error and didn't fully read your question :(

Comment: Thanks Chris. Much appreciated. I've got lots to learn here. Thanks!